# Open unzipped MS Office and LibreOffice files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, git, libreoffice

MS Excel xlsx (and also ODS), are zip files containing XML files and folders of XML files:

1. `[Content_Types].xml`
2. `_rels`
3. `docProps`
4. `xl`

In order to track changes in Git, I have created a repo with the XML files (i.e. the *contents* of the XLSX file). This makes it possible to track changes by file, line and character position.

Git only works in the files are kept unzipped.

Is there a way to open the folder with the contents of the `zip`/`xlsx` file, e.g. my "opening" the `[Content_Types].xml`

N.B. I'm familiar with using uncompressed zipping to keep a single plaintext file in Git, but I want to have the individual files in the repo, not a single plaintext zip.

Comment: I don't understand what's unclear about this. "New" Office files (with x extensions, like docx) are actually ZIPs that contain XML document + some resources. OP wants to track them with git, unzipped, but be able to open these unzipped files. It's unusual, but not unclear IMO.

Comment: Once this has been reopened, the answer is no, outside 3rd party utilities or code, neither of these office software suites can open folders as though they are  files because they are not files.

Comment: Thank you @gronostaj I thought so too

Comment: @music2myear I could not find a macro or anything, but I'm not familiar with that either. Do you have some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Using currently available tools and options this cannot be done.

Yes, the formats are basically zipped collections of various assets, but it does not follow that the programs you named are able to recognize or use an uncompressed collection.

Theoretically, you could use an intermediary tool, or tools, that perform the compression when you wish to open one of these files in the software, and then decompresses the updated file when you save/close it, but I do not know what those tools may be.